# My mouse will periodically "pause" when plugged into a USB hub

Tags: windows-10, usb, input-device

This is a weird one, and I can't track down where to look. When I have a mouse plugged into a hub, it will pause/freeze/hang for about a second every 30 seconds or so. Moving, scrolling and clicking are affected.

I have tried 3 mice (2 wireless, 1 wired) and 2 different hubs (USB, and usbc) every combination of that causes the behavior. If I plug any mouse directly in to a USB port, it works fine.

What would cause the freezing behavior? I have updated to all latest drivers and windows updates. This behavior has been going on for a year, so I can rule out any recent update to cause it.

I am using a Razer Blade Stealth (late 2017 model) laptop

Comment: Could you perhaps state what kind of pc you are using (desktop, laptop) and which model. There may be a case specific to your pc model.

Comment: The Razer Blades Stealth have known issues with USB power and I haven't seen a fix yet...did you try a powered USB hub?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am using this https://www.kensington.com/p/products/connectivity/universal-laptop-docking-stations/sd2000p-usb-c-5gbps-single-4k-nano-dock-w-110w-adapter-hdmi-or-dp-winmacchrome/

Comment: Are you using the 20V wall adapter...? As in: do the lights on the hub stay lit even without the Blade connected to it?

Comment: Yes, I am and it does

Comment: I'd try updating the thunderbolt driver: http://drivers.razersupport.com//index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=2609&nav=0,350,658,660  Check out all the other drivers as well: http://drivers.razersupport.com//index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=660&pcid=658&nav=0,350,658&_ga=2.77761684.1803529751.1580183901-1717228244.1580183901

Comment: My driver's are up to date. :/

Comment: You might want to give your exact model and specs in the post. (Model number, CPU spec, etc.) Maybe someone has repaired this before successfully.

Comment: Hey @Joe did you ever get anywhere with this? I have the same issue on a RZ09-03006E92 Razer Blade 15” (Mid 2019) - Base Model - RTX 2060. I believe it might have something to do with intel integrated graphics because i've never seen it happen while playing a game eg. Counterstrike... I can't get to the bottom of it either. tried a whole bunch of different drivers too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a corsair M65WL and had this same behaviour, it was driving me crazy but I think I've figured it out and maybe it is the same for you.

My on the bottom of the mouse is a switch with three positions:

- Bluetooth
- Off
- Wireless (For the special wireless adapter).

When plugged in to a USB/Hub, at first it seems any of these positions work and USB takes priority.

However, bluetooth/wireless show this freezing behaviour but 'off' (which isn't off if it's plugged into a USB) doesn't. I think 'off' is only really useful if it isn't plugged in as it's to save power.

At a guess, it may be because it's trying to connect periodically via bluetooth or wireless. The fix for me was to switch the the 'off' position when plugged in via USB and it is working fine, but I see the exact same freezing behaviour when the mouse setting is on either of the other two modes.